# Cache for slow API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, cache, promise

I work with an API which answers really slowly. I created a module which constantly asks the API and update some cached value. The code is degraded for study purposes:

```
// module cache.js

const Promise = require('bluebird')

let results

function setter(_results) {
  results = _results
}

function recusriveUpdate() {
  callApi().then(setter)
      .finally(function() {
        return Promise.delay(500)
      }).then(recusriveUpdate)

}

function getter() {
  return results
}

function callApi() {
    // in the real code you will use the real api call
    return Promise.delay(1000).then(()=>Date.now())
}


function initialize() {
  var call = callApi()
  call.then(recusriveUpdate)
  return call.then(setter).then(()=> getter)
}
module.exports = initialize
```

Somewhere in routes.js:

```
// I'm going to use it like this
const cache = require('./cache')()
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.cache = cache
    next()
})


app.get(function(req, res, next) {
    req.cache.then(function(getResults) {
        res.json(getResults())
    }).timeout(1000, Promise.TimeoutError)
    .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function() {
        res.json('cache is emtpty')
    })
})
```